# How do I position the divs in my Spotify homepage footer clone to mimic the original's layout?

Tags: html, css

A couple questions:

1. How do I make the text in `<div class="mh-top-links">` align left?
2. How do I make the social media links in `<div class="mh-social-icons">` display in a row?
3. How do I make the links in `<div class="mh-bottom-links">` display in a row?
4. Overall, how would you arrange the divs in the footer to make it appear the way it does on the original website? See photo for reference.

I've messed around with Chrome DevTools and tried everything I can think of, but I'm still very new to this and don't know what I'm doing. **If you can please provide an explanation along with your answer** so I can apply the logic on my own next time, that'd be greatly appreciated!

[image]

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #222326;
    background-color: #FFF;

    margin: 0;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
    background: #000;
}

footer .mh-top-links {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

footer .mh-top-links dt{
    color: #919496;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1.4;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

footer .mh-top-links dd {
    padding: 3px 0 15px;
}

footer .mh-top-links a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer .mh-social-icons a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

footer .mh-social-icons {
    list-style: none;
}

footer .mh-country a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer .mh-bottom-links li{
    list-style: none;
}

footer .mh-bottom-links a {
    color: #919496;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #1ED760;
}

footer .footer-logo {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<footer id="mh-footer" class="mh-footer-hover">
                <nav>
                    <div class="mh-brand">
                        <a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">
                            <span class="footer-logo">
                                Spotify
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mh-top-links">
                        <dl class="empresa">
                            <dt>Empresa</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Acerca de
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Empleo
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    For the Record
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="comunidades">
                            <dt>Comunidades</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Para artistas
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Desarrolladores
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Publicidad
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Inversores
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Proveedores
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="enlaces">
                            <dt>Enlaces &Uacute;tiles</dt>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Ayuda
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Reproductor web
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd>
                                <a href="#">
                                    App gratis para m&oacute;vil
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mh-social-icons">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Instagram">
                                    <span>IG</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Twitter">
                                    <span>TW</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="Facebook">
                                    <span>FB</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mh-country">
                        <a href="#">
                            Espa&ntilde;a
                            <img src="https://country-flags.scdn.co/flags/es.svg" alt="Spanish flag" class="flag">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mh-bottom-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Legal</a>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Centro de Privacidad</a>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Politica de Privacidad</a>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Cookies</a>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Informacion sobre los anuncios</a>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                        <span class="copyright">&copy; 2020 Spotify AB</span>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </footer>
            </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Flexbox is the best thing to use to layout things like this. There are lots of other ways of doing it (floats, CSS Grid, tables etc..), but Flexbox allows you to do it with the least amount of hacks, the least amount of code, and is also pretty much universally supported, as long as you don't need to support IE. [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) demonstrates the support, so be sure to check first and make a decision based on your requirements.

In my example, I have simplified the code somewhat and added some HTML colors to make it clearer what is going on. I have also created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/cL3k0qjb/) of it.

The general solution is to separate the content into two main rows and apply `display:flex` to each of these. I have had to rearrange the HTML a bit to facilitate this. `justify-content: flex-start` makes the content align to the left. `align-items: flex-start;` prevents the elements stretching across the height of the row. The social media icons have been forced to align right by the trick of adding `margin-left: auto` to their containing element.

Flexbox is also used to layout content in some of the nested containers, such as for the legal links and the social media icons to force them to display in a row.

Some of the alignment problems you have are due to browser styling defaults, for example the `dd` element has a default margin set on it, so it's a good idea to use a CSS reset stylesheet to remove all of these in order to prevent unwelcome surprises. I happen to like [Meyer's](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) because it just blasts everything away, but it should be said that some people prefer something less drastic.

Another problem you have is that the circular borders round your social media icons are a bit skewed. This happens because the elements themselves are not perfectly square. The solution is to force them to be so by setting a width and height on them.

```
<footer id="mh-footer" class="mh-footer-hover">
  <nav>
    <div class="row-1">
      <div class="mh-brand">
        <a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">
          <span class="footer-logo">
            Spotify
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="mh-top-links">
        <dl class="mh-top-links__list">
          <dt>Empresa</dt>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Acerca de
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Empleo
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              For the Record
            </a>
          </dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="mh-top-links__list">
          <dt>Comunidades</dt>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Para artistas
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Desarrolladores
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Publicidad
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Inversores
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Proveedores
            </a>
          </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="mh-top-links__list">
          <dt>Enlaces &Uacute;tiles</dt>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Ayuda
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              Reproductor web
            </a>
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <a href="#">
              App gratis para m&oacute;vil
            </a>
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <ul class="mh-social-icons">
        <li>
          <a class="mh-social-icon" href="#" title="Instagram">
            <span>IG</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="mh-social-icon" href="#" title="Twitter">
            <span>TW</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="mh-social-icon" href="#" title="Facebook">
            <span>FB</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

      <div class="row-2">
        <ul class="mh-legal-links">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Legal</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Centro de Privacidad</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Politica de Privacidad</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Cookies</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Informacion sobre los anuncios</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="mh-country-copyright">
          <div class="mh-country">
            <a href="#">
              Espa&ntilde;a
              <img src="https://country-flags.scdn.co/flags/es.svg" alt="Spanish flag" class="flag">
            </a>
          </div>
          <span class="copyright">&copy; 2020 Spotify AB</span>
        </div>
      </div>
 
  </nav>
</footer>
```

```
/* reset browser styles in one place */
body,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.row-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: pink;
}

.mh-brand {
  background: chartreuse;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.mh-top-links {
  display: flex;
  background: orange;
  width: 50%;
}

.mh-top-links__list {
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: purple;
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.mh-social-icons {
  display: flex;
  background: chocolate;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.mh-social-icon {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: grey;
}

.row-2 {
  display: flex;
  background: coral;
}

.mh-legal-links {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.mh-legal-links > li {
  margin: 5px;
  background: blanchedalmond;
}

.mh-country-copyright {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below code for Question 1 - 3

You can just add the properties to your existing classes.

First line is for question 1. The second line of code is for Question 2 & 3

```
.mh-top-links{align-items: flex-start}

.mh-social-icons li , .mh-bottom-links li{ display:inline;}
```

The fourth question HTML layout as per below

```
<footer id="mh-footer" class="mh-footer-hover">
    <nav class="navclass">
        <div class="mh-brand svelte-1cgydzu">LOGO</span></a></div> 
        
    <div class="mh-top-links">
        <dl class="classname">
            <dt class="classname">Company</dt>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">About</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#/" class="mh-footer-primary">Jobs</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">For the Record</a> </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="classname">
            <dt class="classname">Communities</dt>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">For Artists</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">Developers</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">Advertising</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary ">Investors</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">Vendors</a> </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="classname">
            <dt class="classname">Useful links</dt>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">Help</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">Web Player</a> </dd>
                <dd class="classname"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-primary">Free Mobile App</a> </dd>
        </dl>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="mh-social-icons">
        <ul class="classname">
            <li class="classname"><a href="https://instagram.com/" class="mh-footer-primary"><span class="mh-social-icon-instagram"></span></a></li>
            <li class="classname"><a href="https://facebook.com/" class="mh-footer-primary"><span class="mh-social-icon-fb"></span></a></li>
            <li class="classname"><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="mh-footer-primary"><span class="mh-social-icon-tw"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="mh-country">
        <a href="#/" class="mh-footer-secondary mh-compact">Coutry</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mh-bottom-links">
    <ul class="yourclass">
        <li class="yourclass"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-secondary">Legal</a> </li>
        <li class="yourclass"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-secondary">Privacy Center</a> </li>
        <li class="yourclass"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-secondary">Privacy Policy</a> </li>
        <li class="yourclass"><a href="#/" class="mh-footer-secondary">Cookies</a> </li>
        <li class="yourclass"><a href="#" class="mh-footer-secondary">About Ads</a> </li>
    </ul> 
    
    <span class="class">© 2020 Spotify AB</span>
    </div>
    </nav>

</footer>
```

Just add your own class names :)